# LSAdapter store.find(type, id) tries to push a new record?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use LSAdapter (https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter) in my ember application. I have only one page which is called index. I use the localstorage to persist the data even when refreshing the page so there will only be one record in the LocalStorage for the index page.

When I try to bind the model to the controller via the index route, I get this error :

`Assertion failed: You must include an "id" in a hash passed to "push"`

However, if there is a record in the localstorage, everything works fine.

Here is my IndexRoute :

```
PC.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    var modelId = this.get('store').modelFor(this.routeName);
    return this.get('store').find(this.routeName, modelId);
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

How do I get rid of this error ?

Do I need to manually check in the LocalStorage without using the LSAdapter ? But that would defeat the purpose of the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue and ended up patching the adapter (https://github.com/musicist288/ember-localstorage-adapter/commit/60313970d6591be51cd29c6137367721465294fc). In my application I needed a find or create behavior so I ended up with the following:

```
App.Route = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        var store = this.get('store');

        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
           store.find("school", params.school_id).then(function (model) {
                resolve(model);
           }).catch(function () {
                resolve(store.push("school", App.SchoolFixtures.findBy('id', params.school_id)));
           });
        });
    }
});
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shall try your fix as soon as I have time to work on this project.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for the input ! I managed to acheive my plan with what you provided. However, I had some problem. It seems that the store.find("school", id) adds a school object in the cache array of the store accessible via this :`store.typeMapsFor("school").idToRecord`. I add to remove it before rejecting the promise so I added `store.dematerializeRecord(store.typeMapFor(type).idToRecord[id]);` right before the reject(); of your github patch.

Comment: For info, I did not use any Fixtures. My catch code looks like this : `resolve(store.createRecord("school", { id: params.school_id}));`. Replace "school" and params.school_id with whatever the model you use it for.

Comment: Also, another problem with the patch was that in the catch function, the call to `store.hasRecordForId("school", params.school_id);` returns `true` but shoudl still return `false`.

Comment: Thanks for follow up.  I just updated the repo with `store.dematerializeRecord` and added the test for `store.hasRecordForId`

Answer (score 0):

This fix has been merged in the main branch of LSAdapter.

https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/pull/66

It now works out of the box from the official repo at https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter